# What should I call a method checking if two entities refers the same db entity?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

I have entity objects that are synchronized with a database. I commonly use these entities in three different comparisons:

1. Check if two entity objects are the same CLR object.
2. Check if all properties of two entity objects are equal.
3. Check if two entity objects refer to the same database entity, even if some properties differ.

For 1 I use Object.ReferenceEquals(). 
For 2 I overwrite Equals() checking all properties.
For 3 I have been a bit inconsistent. Some entities have a "Match" method some have a "IsSame" method. The logic of the method compares their primary key and if has not been assigned by the database yet, their secondary key (if they have one).

A lot of code scenarios would be easier if I used Equals for comparing keys (e.g. I could check a list just using Contains()), but I would find it confusing, if Equals only compared the keys and didn't check all properties.

My scenario is an N-Tier system with self-tracking-entities. I often need to update a list of entities or similar with an updated entity arriving from another tier.

Is there a consensus for naming a method checking if two entities refers to the same logical entity? KeyEquals()? SameEntity()?

Answer (score 2):

DbEquivalent()?

Comment: Not bad, but maybe a little too concrete referring to their persistence in a database. What the entities share are their keys, they refer to the same "physical" thing, but being stored in a database is more "coincidental".

Comment: @Holstebroe: Well in my case whenever I use an id, it's because I'm about to do something with the datastore.  I don't agree that two entities with the same Id are the same 'physical' thing, the ids are are a datastore level concern.